# How to embed fonts with pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf, embedding

In last 3-4 days I tried to embed to my `pdf` file fonts, that it contains. I visit more links, including questions from `tex.stackexchange.com`, and I achieve it even. But yesterday I have seen, that fonts are not embedded again.

I use non-latex font. I've created `tfm` and `afm` files and added them to `myfonts.map` file. Also I've made `updmap-sys --enable Map=myfonts.map` for adding my map file. And it is added to updmap. I've checked `~/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map` and it contains in tail next.

```
% myfonts.map
recarial ArialMT " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc
recarialbd Arial-BoldMT " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc
recarialbdo Arial-BoldMT " .167 SlantFont T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc
recarialbi Arial-BoldItalicMT " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc
recarialbio Arial-BoldItalicMT " .167 SlantFont T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc
recariali Arial-ItalicMT " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc
recarialio Arial-ItalicMT " .167 SlantFont T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc
recarialo ArialMT " .167 SlantFont T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc
```

For generating `afm` and `tfm` files I use next commands http://vpaste.net/9yytH. File `ttfonts.map` I don't use.

For including fonts to document I've created `arial.sty` file.

```
\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{arial}{}%

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{arial}{b}{n}{<->ecarialbd}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{arial}{b}{sl}{<-> ecarialbdo}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{arial}{b}{it}{<-> ecarialbi}{}%

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{arial}{m}{n}{<-> ecarial}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{arial}{m}{sl}{<-> ecarialo}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{arial}{m}{it}{<-> ecariali}{}%

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{arial}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * arial/b/n}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{arial}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * arial/b/sl}{}%
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{arial}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * arial/b/it}{}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{arial}%
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{arial}%
```

I compile my document by `pdflatex`. I don't know how, but after compilation by `latex` and getting `dvi`, I get broken markup. I mean that I get ugly document. Also, when I compile `dvi` and convert it to `pdf`, I see, that text are become raster. It is unreadable on big scaling. And document is still ugly.

Also I've added to `updmap.cfg` option `pdftexDownloadBase14 true` by command `updmap --edit`. This is packages, that I use http://vpaste.net/biTOJ. It contains:

- `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
- `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

I'm using next software:

- Kubuntu 14.04
- pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
  kpathsea version 6.1.1
  Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.50
  Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
  Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5
- TexStudio 2.6.6

About custom fonts. I use not only Arial, also I use another fonts, but I point Arial as popular font.

How can I fix embedding fonts to pdf document? Sorry if my english is not clear. I can clarify anything, if something is strange. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add the real font name to the map file entries, e.g. `recarial ArialMT " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc <arial.ttf`. If the real font is a ttf (and not a pfb) it is better to compile with pdflatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for prompt response!!! It works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the real font name to the map file entries, e.g.

```
 recarial ArialMT " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <T1-WGL4.enc <arial.ttf.
```

If the real font is a .ttf (and not a .pfb) it is better to compile with pdflatex.